# Filling array with random "cards" of enum

Tags: c#, methods, random, enums, instantiation

Classic deck of cards/poker game issue. I have classes for each card (CardClubs, CardDiamond, etc). I have an enum for Rank (Deuce = 2, etc). In my CardSet class, I have the constructor:

```
    public SuperCard[] cardArray;
    public Random myRandom = new Random();
    #region Constructor
    public CardSet() 
    {
        cardArray = new SuperCard[52];
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            cardArray[i] = new CardClubs((Rank)i + 1);
            cardArray[i + 13] = new CardDiamond((Rank)i+1);
            cardArray[i + 26] = new CardHeart((Rank)i + 1); ;
            cardArray[i + 39] = new CardSpades((Rank)i + 1); ;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

And I have the method GetCards, which passes in the number of cards to get. I created the public random up top. GetCards is called in the Program.cs, as such:

```
int howManyCards = 5; // can be whatever. used this instead of # for debug purposes
SuperCard[] computerHand = myDeck.GetCards(howManyCards); // create two hands, user/comp
SuperCard[] myHand = myDeck.GetCards(howManyCards);
```

I am not understanding how to use random to generate the random card. here is my current GetCard method (which isn't working) also from the CardSet class. For now, its okay if it generates the same card, just want to understand the basics of random selection.

```
    public SuperCard[] GetCards(int number)
    { 
        SuperCard[] hand = new SuperCard[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            hand[i] = cardArray[myRandom]((Rank)i + 1);
        }
        return hand;
    }
```

Comment: I realize it's not related to the question you asked but it seems awkward to use subclasses for the suits.

Comment: @couchand they have their own override methods to abstract methods from the parent class SuperCard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Random class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

```
 var r = new Random();
 r.Next(min,max);
```

Comment: This worked:
`public SuperCard[] GetCards(int number)
        { 
            SuperCard[] hand = new SuperCard[number];
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                hand[i] = cardArray[myRandom.Next(1,52)];
            }
            return hand;
        }`